# Start with existing graph db

Tags: neo4j, structr

I was just watching the [Belgium Beer demo](https://vimeo.com/85811064) and I would like to replicate the same process to start structr with an existing neo4j graph.

Unfortunately if do the following steps:

1. Extract the downloaded structr folder.
2. Create a folder structr/db and copy the content of my graph.db.
3. Start structr with appropriate version of this command: 
   java -cp lib/*;structr-ui-1.1-SNAPSHOT-201505231136.f596a.jar     org.structr.Server

I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Vital service NodeService failed to start: Error starting
>   org.neo4j.kern el.EmbeddedGraphDatabase,
>   c:\Users\DataToValue\Documents\structr.\db. Aborting

Any idea how I could start a structr project with an existing graph db?

Comment: There must be more lines in the log giving insight to the root cause of the failing startup. The Structr version you used is compiled against Neo4j 2.1.8. The database has to be created or upgraded to the same version to be functional with this Structr version.

Comment: Without further information from the log it's difficult to help as we can only guess what prevented the server to start. It's most likely an old database version, so you might need to add a file `neo4j.conf` in the `db` folder with a single line containing `allow_database_upgrade=true`.

Answer (score 1):

Not *entirely* sure what your goal is, but... you cannot simply use a product with an existing database, just because it uses a database brand which matches what you're already using (in this case, Neo4j). Structr (or any product, for that matter), will have its own data schema, its own product-specific metadata, etc. There's really no way to simply swap out a product's database and swap in your own (unless it was essentially a backup/instance from that product's database content).

Answer (score 1):

With upcoming structr 2.1 version it it possible to specify an external/ existing neo4j DB instance as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43583403/1821792