# Structr, existing Neo4j installation and cypher shell

Tags: structr

I have the following installations on my Windows 7 machine :

1. Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.0
2. Structr-ui-2.0.1

I had first installed Neo4j, then Structr UI.

I am able to run Structr UI and create a schema, add nodes and relationships.

I have the following questions :

1. I guess that Structr starts and uses it's own, independent neo4j instance. Whenever I have my already-installed Neo4j started, Structr throws an exception saying the address 7474 is already bound
2. I cannot connect to this 'internal' Neo4j instance from Cypher shell (using the bat file from my existing instance, providing port no. etc.)
3. I wish to use both Structr UI as well as Cypher shell. The best way to do this is ask Structr to use my existing Neo4j instance rather than it's internal one

How shall I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, correct. Structr starts its own embedded Neo4j database, so if you start Neo4j first, Structr tries to bind to the same ports Neo4j does, and fails because the ports are already in use.
2. Structr has no connector for the Cypher shell, so you won't be able to connect to the internal Neo4j instance.
3. Use the latest Structr Snapshot (2.1) from https://structr.org/repositories/snapshots/org/structr/structr-ui/2.1.0-SNAPSHOT/structr-ui-2.1.0-20170202.205126-26-dist.zip. This version supports connecting to a remote Neo4j database using the following configuration settings in your structr.conf configuration file:

   ```
   database.driver.mode = remote
   database.connection.url = bolt://localhost:7687
   database.connection.username = neo4j
   database.connection.password = neo4j
   ```

You will have to adapt the above settings to fit your Neo4j installation.

Comment: I have the same issue and your solution under 3. works for me. However I have a naked neo4j DB and the user account data seems to be missing from it. So how can I import the required data for structur so that I can at least log in again?